# Optuna sample fixed parameter depending on another parameter

Tags: python, hyperparameters, optuna

In my setting I have an abstract situation like this the following, just note this is not about power calculation but a simple example to explain my point.

```py
base = trial.suggest_int(1, 3)
power = trial.suggest_int(1, 10)
```

As when the `base == 1` the power parameter becomes useless and would like to fix it to 1.

For example:

```py
base = trial.suggest_int("base", 1, 3)
if base == 1:
   # Different distribution! But still inside the other.
   power = trial.suggest_int("power", 1, 1) 
else:
   power = trial.suggest_int("power", 1, 10)
```

While this works it creates later problems in the form of `ValueError`s because the underlying distributions are not the same.

---

How can I suggest a fixed value **with the same parameter name** that depends on another value that is sampled within the trial?